# Ping user above embeded message Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I had a small question, how do I add a ping above the user. I have tried this and it shows no errors.

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Member"));
    let mention = `<@${member}>`;
    embed.setColor("#2465ff");
    embed.setDescription(".");
    embed.setFooter("We now have " + member.guild.memberCount + " members!");
    embed.setTimestamp();
    member.guild.channels.cache.get("822024147202080771").send(embed);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is most likely a more efficient way to do this, however the way I achieved it is by sending the embed, and then editing the message and sending the mention afterwards.

For example:

```js
message.channel.send(embed).then(m => {
    m.edit(`<@${member.id}>`);
})
```

Comment: Note that the one issue with this is that it has to send two different requests to the Discord API and therefor if your bot is doing a lot of things at once, there may be a slight delay between the message being sent and the message being edited.

Comment: Thank you, I have added this and I get this error: ReferenceError: message is not defined

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Replace `message.channel` with `member.guild.channels.cache.get('822024147202080771')` from your code and it should work fine.

Comment: Great to hear. If you press the tick next to my answer to mark it as correct, then people in the future who have the same question can easily find the solution.